# LuaTeX bug? Abrupt stop

Tags: luatex, miktex

I'm on Windows, with latest and fully updated MiKTeX.  I try to compile a document with `lualatex test.tex` where test.tex is

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
code
\end{document}
```

LuaTeX stops without any error message. In the console it says

```
("D:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty"(using cache:

 C:/Users/M├írton/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic)
Sorry, but lualatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/M├írton/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/lualatex.log
```

but because my username has accents in it, the mentioned log file is in fact in

```
  C:/Users/Márton/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/lualatex.log
```

and its contents are

```
2016-04-28 19:51:39,822+0200 FATAL lualatex - MultiByteToWideChar() did not succeed; last error code is 1113
2016-04-28 19:51:59,022+0200 FATAL lualatex - MultiByteToWideChar() did not succeed; last error code is 1113
2016-04-28 20:04:06,131+0200 FATAL lualatex - MultiByteToWideChar() did not succeed; last error code is 1113
2016-04-28 20:10:33,633+0200 FATAL lualatex - MultiByteToWideChar() did not succeed; last error code is 1113
2016-04-28 20:10:45,353+0200 FATAL lualatex - MultiByteToWideChar() did not succeed; last error code is 1113
2016-04-28 20:10:58,151+0200 FATAL lualatex - MultiByteToWideChar() did not succeed; last error code is 1113
2016-04-28 20:11:19,169+0200 FATAL lualatex - MultiByteToWideChar() did not succeed; last error code is 1113
2016-04-28 20:11:52,976+0200 FATAL lualatex - MultiByteToWideChar() did not succeed; last error code is 1113
```

Comment: The miktex binary won't work with the current luaotfload. You could try the newer luatex from the next repository http://miktex.org/announcement/miktex-next-5900. You will then also need the Luaotfload v2.7-fix-1 from here: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/releases (I don't know if it will solve your name problem). There you can also get the older luaotfload 2.6.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer or wait for the bugfix... so it is indeed a bug. I'll use XeTeX for now. Thanks.

Comment: Bugfixes don't happen out-of-blue. Someone has to report the problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is it a MiKTeX or a LuaTeX bug? where can I check if it's reported already and report it if not?

Comment: Imho there wasn't a update of some binary, only luaotfload. So if there is a bug it is probably in luaotfload. But you will have to test it with the new luatex from miktex next. Or find a texlive 2016 pretester with such an user name.

Comment: This is a bizarre problem: The offending symbol, ``MultiByteToWideChar``,
is used only in  zlib and kpse. AFAICS neither call site would print this
silly error message. Perhaps it’s some obscure Windows API? In any case
it would shed a light on the problem if you could run Luatex in GDB and
set a breakpoint at that function and post the backtrace to the Luatex
list.

Also the terminology is funny: If it indeed encountered an uppercase fatal error it should terminate, not continue until it runs into the same
issue again.

Comment: @PhilippGesang I need instructions on how to do that. Do you think http://www.readytext.co.uk/?p=3712 is correct and sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug seems to be fixed in latest LuaTeX from MiKTeX.