# Help me debug LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, miktex, windows, accents, debugging

I still have the problem I asked about a year ago. ([LuaTeX bug? Abrupt stop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306901)) When I compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
code
\end{document}
```

with `lualatex test.tex`, it fails, and writes the following error log:

```
2017-03-19 12:54:10,614+0100 FATAL lualatex - MultiByteToWideChar() did not succeed; last error code is 1113
```

I am certain the problem is caused by my Windows username (Márton), which contains an accented letter, and because of this, when some component of LuaTeX attempts to read or write some file in `C:\Users\Márton\AppData` they do a wrong encoding conversion and then fail.

Under the other question I received a comment saying

> In any case it would shed a light on the problem if you could run Luatex in GDB and set a breakpoint at that function and post the backtrace to the Luatex list.

My question is, is it possible to debug the MiKTeX-supplied luatex.exe (does it include debug symbols), or do I need to build it from source (which seems [hell of an ordeal](http://www.readytext.co.uk/?cat=8))?

Comment: I don't use MikTeX or Windows (and I don't have accented characters in my username on my Linux machine here), so I can't test this,  but does this happen with `pdflatex` as well? That tiny test document above does not make use of lua features (or XeLaTeX).

Comment: There is a bug report regarding this https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2586/ but it says that the behaviour is irreproducible. You could try if a trace give some info https://miktex.org/diagnosing. You can also add a comment to the bug above. Christian can perhaps make you a special version to debug the problem. But first make sure that you really have the newest versions of everything!  Or try texlive.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You should make it clearer that you mean Christian Schenk (provider of MikTeX), in my point of view ;-) Otherwise it is a little bit confusing

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry ;-)

Comment: Does is fail also if you run luatex (not lualatex) on a simple file `abc\bye`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, it doesn't.

Comment: And if you input and use luaotfload? (`\input{luaotfload.sty}\font\test={file:lmroman12-regular.otf}\test blub \bye`)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It fails then. (I have the miktex-next version of both.)

Comment: Although this does not solve the bug (assuming bug), it may help the OP: Both MiKtex and TeXlive can be installed as portable. Then, it may be possible to install to a path that is not in the User home directory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was due to a bug that has been fixed.