# Lualatex produces no output (MiKTeX)

Tags: luatex, miktex, luaotfload

My lualatex on MiKTeX seems to be somehow broken:

If I compile any document, like the following, LuaLaTeX produces no output at all (no .pdf, .aux, .log, ...).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}
```

In the command line, this gets printed:

```
lualatex lua.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.11.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./lua.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
```

From there on it takes 2min until the program is finished. 
If do the same with pdflatex or xelatex it works flawlessly.

This is the MiKTeX diagnose report:

```
Date: 2019-12-27 14:02:37
MiKTeX: 2.9.7250
OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit, build 18363
SharedSetup: yes
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheckAdmin: 2019-12-27 01:32:05
LastUpdateAdmin: 2019-12-24 14:24:17
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: yes
AdminMode: yes
Root0: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

I built lualatex new and refreshed the FNDB (in both admin and user mode). Any tips?

**EDIT**

Compiling

```
abc \bye
```

with `luatex` works, while

```
\input luaotfload.sty
abc \bye
```

again results in no output. This is the command line text:

```
luatex lua.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.11.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./lua.tex ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.tex")
```

**EDIT**
This one doesn't work as well:

```
luaotfload-tool -u
*** UTF-8 conversion failed; func=miktex_utf8__stat64i32, utf8="C:\Users\myname/.", error=1113
```

`myname` in fact contains german umlauts which appear to be wrong, but that shouldn't be the problem (see a similar case [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306901/luatex-bug-abrupt-stop#comment746474_306901)).

Comment: What happens if you run `abc \bye` with luatex (not lualatex)?

Comment: It produces an .pdf with "abc" and page number 1. A log gets produced as well. Just as it should (?).

Comment: Just curious. What happens if you change the name of the file?

Comment: What happens if you add `\input luaotfload.sty` to the luatex example?

Comment: 1.) Changing the name doesn't change the result.
2.) If I add `\input luaotfload.sty` to the example, then it produces no output and clears the log file and gets stuck for some minutes as with lualatex. I will add the console output to my post.

Comment: What happens if you run `luaotfload-tool -u` ? is the database created?

Comment: It isn't created. See extended question.

Comment: Today I reinstalled MiKTeX completely. Nothing changed except for one thing: The first time (only!) I tried to run the extended luatex example, I got this message `luatex lua.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.11.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
 restricted system commands enabled.
I can't find the format file 'luatex.fmt'!`

Comment: @UltimateTrick The error `1113` you get from `miktex_utf8__stat64i32` stands for `ERROR_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION` which occurs only if the original text contains invalid UTF-8. Given that the problem occurs while converting `C:\Users\myname/.`, there must be something going on with the `myname` part. I don't think that anyone will be able to help you without the unmodified error message containing the invalid UTF-8 part.

Comment: It contains an "ä" originally which gets wrongly displayed as "õ" and one whitespace " " beside from the usual ASCII characters.

Comment: @UltimateTrick Does the "ä" get displayed as "õ " or does the whitespace appear independently in the name?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear formulation: "ä" gets displayed as "õ " and whitespace appears independently of that (just mentioned this, because whitespace is a common cause of path problems...).

Comment: There is now a bug report on the Miktex bug tracker for this.
https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my previous answer got deleted for being irrelevant, here it is again, now including the requested solution as the bug is now fixed.

There is a bug report on the Miktex bug tracker for this issue. This issue was fixed end of June 2020. https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/552. The problem had to do with file name handling in LuaLatex. Installing the most recent version of Miktex (newer than 2020.06) solves the problem.

Comment: As I don't use Windows/MiKTeX anymore, I can not confirm this, but the bug tracker indeed seems to suggest that this issue is now fixed.