# LuaLaTeX produces no output in Flatpak TeXLive

Tags: luatex, texlive, luaotfload, texlive-2020

I'm currently working on getting TeXLive usable in Linux Flatpaks, however LuaLaTeX "silently" fails and I have no idea what might be wrong or where to start.  The output and symptoms are not unlike [Lualatex produces no output (MiKTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521982/lualatex-produces-no-output-miktex), however I'm neither on Windows with UCS/ANSI encoding, nor are my files or `$HOME` in a non-ASCII path, nor am I using MikTeX.

I'm reusing the mwe from the linked question:

Compiling

```tex
abc \bye
```

with `luatex` works but if I load the otf package:

```tex
\input luaotfload.sty
abc \bye
```

I get:

```
$ luatex mwe.tex 
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./mwe.tex
(/usr/lib/sdk/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty
(/usr/lib/sdk/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.tex)
```

It may be notable that the last line of the output/log is missing a newline which may indicate a crash of the engine(?).

Furthermore, running `luaotfload-tool -u` even with highest verbosity doesn't give any output at all.  However, for what it's worth, ConTeXt MkIV (i.e. using LuaTeX as backend) works fine.

My first assumption was that the Flatpak being based on the DVD release of TeXLive 2020 without any updates since (including two minor releases of luaotfload) was too old.  I'm currently working on being able to use more recent daily-snapshots of TeXLive in Flatpak (https://github.com/flathub/org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.texlive/pull/28), however this didn't change any of the above behavior (I've confirmed that I'm indeed running luaotfload 3.14 in the Flatpak).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Configure the flathub remote and your distro to have flatpaks in your path, then install TeXLive:

   ```
   $ flatpak install org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.texlive
   ```
2. Run a shell within the Sandbox and put the TeXLive SDK into the PATH:

   ```
   $ flatpak run --command=/usr/bin/sh --devel org.freedesktop.Sdk
   [ org.freedesktop.Sdk ~ ]$ source /usr/lib/sdk/texlive/enable.sh
   ```
3. Create a MWE and build:

   ```
   [ org.freedesktop.Sdk ~ ]$ cat > mwe.tex
   \input luaotfload.sty
   abc \bye
   [ org.freedesktop.Sdk ~ ]$ luatex mwe.tex
   ```

Comment: Ha! That's exactly the bug that I reported yesterday in `luaotfload`.  The problem is that `TEXMFCACHE` is not writable and `luaotfload` does not handle that gracefully and simply crashes.

Comment: See also https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/164 and https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-August/046013.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing the same problem recently when trying to build TeX documents with [Nix](https://nixos.org/).  After some debugging I found out that the fundamental problem is that `TEXMFCACHE` is not writable.  Looking into `texmf.cnf` we find the default values in

```
[ org.freedesktop.Sdk ~]$ cat /usr/lib/sdk/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf  | grep -e '^TEXMFVAR' -e '^TEXMFSYSVAR' -e '^TEXMFCACHE'
TEXMFSYSVAR = $TEXMFROOT/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR = ~/.texlive2020/texmf-var
TEXMFCACHE = $TEXMFSYSVAR;$TEXMFVAR
```

For Flatpak, some are being overriden by the `./install-tl -portable` option as part of the packaging process of the Flatpak:

```
[ org.freedesktop.Sdk ~]$ cat /usr/lib/sdk/texlive/texmf.cnf | grep -e '^[^%]'
TEXMFLOCAL = $SELFAUTOPARENT/texmf-local
TEXMFHOME = $TEXMFLOCAL
TEXMFVAR = $TEXMFSYSVAR
TEXMFCONFIG = $TEXMFSYSCONFIG
ASYMPTOTE_HOME = $TEXMFCONFIG/asymptote
```

So originally `TEXMFCACHE` is defined in terms of `TEXMFSYSVAR` and `TEXMFVAR`.  The first one, `TEXMFSYSVAR`, is usually not writable on most systems, whereas the latter, `TEXMFVAR`, is assumed to always be writable.
This assumption of course fails if everything is mounted as a read-only overlay of the system, like on Nix.

In the Flatpak the issue is not the same, but related, as `TEXMFVAR` and thus also `TEXMFCACHE` point to `TEXMFSYSVAR` only (due to the `-portable` option).  As this directory is read-only, this fails as well.

Luckily you can override the values in `texmf.cnf` by just setting environment variables of the same name.  So for instance we could use

```
$ flatpak run --env=TEXMFVAR=/tmp --command=/usr/bin/sh --devel org.freedesktop.Sdk
```

Here I chose `TEXMFVAR=/tmp`, but any other directory that is guaranteed to writable would work as well, e.g. `TEXMFVAR=/run/user/$(id -u)`.  For Flatpaks it would be reasonable to set them to their (not the hosts!) `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` value, e.g. `~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/cache/texmf-var` when using the SDK within VS Code.

Merely setting `TEXMFCACHE` would solve the `luaotfload` problem, as well.  However, if you need to generate `tfm` or `pk` fonts on the fly you will hit a wall again, because this needs write-access to `TEXMFVAR`.

Comment: What a coincidence, and I thought I was the odd one trying to use TeX in Flatpaks :)
I've run `flatpak run --env=TEXMFVAR=$XDG_CACHE_HOME/texmf-var --command=/usr/bin/sh --devel org.freedesktop.Sdk` and this works (as XDG_CACHE_HOME is set properly in Flatpak).  I see that the silent errors are being handled upstream, that's nice!

Comment: However I wanted to now build a Flatpak that has the desired behavior from the start, but now I cannot reproduce the bug anymore.  Ever since I ran `run` with `--env` the problem doesn't occur anymore and the cache is built in `$HOME/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/cache/texmf-var/` and I've got no idea why this happens. I've removed any overrides/configs/caches that I can think of; but that's no question for TeX.SX I guess :)

Comment: Oh found the error in my thoughts: The actual texmf.cnf isn't in `/usr/lib/sdk/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` but in `/usr/lib/sdk/texlive/texmf.cnf`, I'll propose an edit to this answer. I hope I can provide a fixed flatpak soon-ish.

Comment: Fixed build: https://github.com/flathub/org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.texlive/pull/29

Comment: @ljrk `/usr/lib/sdk/texlive/texmf.cnf` is the system-specific `texmf.cnf` and should actually be empty.  It is meant to put your overrides for the default values into this file.  The file `/usr/lib/sdk/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` is the one that contains the values that were specified during installation.

Comment: It contains the values as chosen by the installer which are different from the default when choosing e.g. a portable installation or otherwise adjusting them (as I do in my PR for the Flatpak).  As the Flatpak is originally packaged using `-portable`, `TEXMFVAR` is set there to just `$TEXMFSYSVAR`, as otherwise this would not fail since the SDK package, despite being sandboxed, has limited access to the home directory, notably also ~/.texlive2020/texmf-var.

Comment: I think my most recent edit better reflects the problem.